# how to use strings which annotation with @Value in order to join the other strings?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I want to use Strings which have Annotation @Value but If I try them join to another a string they turns a null object.If I use just them they works well.What I need to do use them to join another a string or those strings cannot join other strings?

```
 @Value("${Example.com}")
private String HOST_NAME;

private String BASE_URL="http://"+HOST_NAME+":8080";

System.out.println(HOST_NAME);
// Output is 123.123.123.1123;(For example)
System.out.println(BASE_URL);
// Output like that http://null:8080;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here :

```
private String BASE_URL="http://"+HOST_NAME+":8080";
```

`HOST_NAME` is `null` because in Java, field initializers are evaluated before the class constructor but at the Spring startup, Spring values fields annotated with `@Value` such as :

```
@Value("${Example.com}")
private String HOST_NAME;
```

only after the constructor be invoked.

So to solve your requirement, set `BASE_URL` in the constructor such as :

```
private String BASE_URL;
public FooClass(){
   BASE_URL="http://"+HOST_NAME+":8080";
}
```

Not your question but you could use a constructor injection with `@Value`. It makes the class less Spring dependent and more unit-testable.

```
private String BASE_URL;
private String HOST_NAME;

public FooClass(@Value("${Example.com}") String hostName){
   this.HOST_NAME = hostName;
   this.BASE_URL="http://"+HOST_NAME+":8080";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because sprint initializes properties after object construction.

A solution for this could be storing an entire pattern in you properties:

```
hostname=example.com
port=8080
base-url=http://${hostname}:${port}
```

The use `base-url`:

```
@Value("${base-url}")
private String baseUrl;

// ...

System.out.println(baseUrl); // Will print http://example.com:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are getting the `BASE_URL="http://null:8080";` , because  field initializers are evaluated after the bean is created.

I had similar problem and i came up with this:

```
@Value("http://${Example.com}:8080")
private String HOST_NAME;
```

> Now your `HOST_NAME` will have the value : http://*whatever.com*:8080